# removing the date from a PDF-Latex output through IPython Notebook conversion

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I remove the date from a PDF-Latex output through IPython Notebook conversion? I have tried removing so many packages in the Latex document but the date doesn't seem to be removed

Answer (score -1):

Download the IPython/Jupyter ipynb file as (la)tex file. Open the tex file and add the line

```
\date{}
```

just before

```
\maketitle
```

Then compile the tex file with with `pdflatex`.